# Why does the one-point closed string tachyon amplitude on the disk vanish at tree-level?

Tags: string-theory, correlation-functions

I would like to understand the amplitude of the coupling between $N$ open strings and one closed string at tree-level.

I know this coupling takes place in the disk topology.

Why does the amplitude vanish in the cases $N=0$ and 1 (so a single closed string on the disk, and one open-one closed string on the disk)

I think this should be clear from momentum considerations, but I don't see why. Could someone explain this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't think it's about infinite volume for less than 3 vertex operators, because inserting one closed string on the disk means that you insert a vertex operator in the bulk of the disk (as opposed to on the boundary, like you do for open strings), and doing this leaves only U(1) rotational symmetry left, which has finite volume, and so dividing by this volume doesn't zero out the amplitude! But thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us define the amplitude that you are interested in:
$$\mathcal{A}^{N,1}(p_1,\ldots,p_N,p) \sim g_\text{s}^{N/2}\frac{1}{\operatorname{vol}(\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R}))}\left<\prod_{i=1}^N \left(\int_{\partial\mathbb{D}^2}\mathrm{d}^2 x_i\ V_\text{o}^{p_i}(x_i)\right)\int_{\mathbb{D}^2}\mathrm{d}^2 z\ V_\text{c}^p(z,\bar{z})   \right>,$$
where $N$ is the number of open string insertions, sitting on the boundary of the disk, with $V_\text{o}^{p_i}$ being the vertex operators associated to these insertions, and $V_\text{c}^p$ denotes the single closed string state, inserted in the interior of the disk and $\sim$ denotes up to factors of $\alpha'$ and numerical coefficients.

Indeed, as you alluded to in a comment, we can fix the closed string vertex operator to, say, $z=i$ using part of the conformal Killing group and this leaves a residual $\operatorname{U}(1)$ group, that keeps $z=i$ fixed. So the residual conformal Killing group would give a finite volume, which wouldn't be enough to make the amplitude zero when $N=0$ or $N=1$.

So, when $N=0$, the amplitude is purely kinematical, since the insertion is fixed, so
$$\mathcal{A}^{0,1}(p) \sim \delta^{(D)}(p).$$
In your title you mention you are interested in tachyon vertex operators. Close string tachyons satisfy the mass-shell condition
$$p^2 = -\frac{\alpha'}{4},$$
therefore the kinematical constraint $p=0$ that the amplitude demands cannot be obeyed by a single tachyon, so the amplitude has to vanish. If you wanted a non-vanishing amplitude you have to look at the massless sector<sup>*</sup>, or you have to do off-shell string theory (which we know very little about).

Similarly, for the $N=1$ amplitude, there is still enough freedom to fix the position of the open string insertion, so you get
$$\mathcal{A}^{1,1}(p_1,p)\sim \delta^{(D)}(p_1+p).$$
Sticking with the tachyon sector, i.e. both the closed and the open string insertions are tachyons we have to be careful. Note that they have different mass-shell conditions, namely $$p^2=-\frac{4}{\alpha'} \qquad\text{but}\qquad p_1^2 = -\frac{1}{\alpha'}.$$
So you cannot satisfy the momentum constraint $p_1+p=0$, so the amplitude has to vanish. If you do not stick to the tachyon sector there are more options.

---

<sup><sup>*</sup>there are other subtleties there, though</sup>